# What does CS:IP mean in assembly and how it works?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I cant understand what `cs:ip` means.  What is the role of `:`?

Comment: Briefly, the syntax is `segment:offset`. In this case **code segment : instruction pointer**. A simple analogy could be **chapter : verse**, where only one chapter is available at a time.

Comment: It's not possible to just "understand" this, it's unlogical special syntax for x86 16b real mode addressing. The total address space is 20 bits large, but two 16 bit values are used to calculate 20b physical address. Search for some x86 real mode addressing segment/offset book/docs/tutorial. This looks to be complete and short enough: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: Your question makes me wonder if you've even tried to google that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the role of `:`?

This colon that separates two registers has different meaning depending on the registers used.

- If the first register **is** a segment register (one of `CS`, `DS`, `ES`, `FS`, `GS`, or `SS`) then the whole "segment register : offset register" notation represents a pointer to a location in the addressable memory (1MB + HMA). To calculate the linear address you would first multiply the value in the segment register by 16 and then add the value in the offset register.
  Examples include `CS:IP`, `SS:SP`, `DS:SI`, `ES:DI`, ...
- If the first register **is not** a segment register then a combination of two 16-bit general purpose registers (GPRs) is used to represent a 32-bit number. In the case of an 8086 simply because its architecture has no 32-bit registers.
  A notation that you'll see a lot is `DX:AX`. The value that this represents is calculated from first multiplying what is in `DX` by 65536 and then adding what is in `AX`.

> I can't understand what `cs:ip` means.

Given that `cs` means "code segment" and that `ip` means "instruction pointer" (this is not a general purpose register!) the combination `cs:ip` represents the location where the CPU is currently fetching instructions to execute.